# json.dumps need additional "," between entries

Tags: python, json

my json.dumps code:

```
print json.dumps({'cidr': item, 'name': 'Malware'}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(', ',    ': '))
```

work fine so far, as it outputs:

```
    {
    "cidr": "98.131.229.2/32", 
    "name": "Malware"
    }
    {
    "cidr": "98.158.178.231/32", 
    "name": "Malware"
    }
```

I need two additional things

- a opening and closing bracket `[ ]` (first and last line)
- an additional `,` between the entries

I tried is with a loop, but that brings me the additional , also at the end (just before the closing ]

so, in the end, I need an output like:

```
[
{
    "cidr": "98.131.229.2/32", 
    "name": "Malware"
}
,
{
    "cidr": "98.158.178.231/32", 
    "name": "Malware"
}
]
```

Can I do this with the standard son tools or do I need to run additional stuff?

I'm not working with dictionaries. Full code:

```
malwareurl = "http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/ip.txt"  # URL to TXT file

    print "Downloading with urllib2"
    f = urllib2.urlopen(malwareurl)
    result = f.read().split("\r\n")
    ips = [x + "/32" for x in result if x]

    for item in ips:
        print json.dumps({'cidr': item, 'name': 'Malware'}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(', ', ': '))
```

Comment: Your example shows dumping one dictionary, but returns two dictionaries. I don't think you are showing us all your code.

Comment: I added the full code

Comment: You _are_ working with dictionaries. That's what `{'cidr': item, ...}` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to build a list, then dump the list:

```
result = []
for item in ips:
    result.append({'cidr': item, 'name': 'Malware'})

print json.dumps(result)
```